# building a multi-city time series regression in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, modeling, fable-r

How would I view a singular model built from am multi-city regression analysis using the Fable package? I'm new to modeling so any help would be appreciated- thanks!

When building a time-series regression model using the TSLM function in the Fable package, I receive a warning that says

`Warning: Model reporting is only supported for individual models, so a glance will be shown. To see the report for a specific model, use` select()`and`filter()`to identify a single model.`
The code I'm using is this:

```
tsdf %>% 
  model(TSLM(dy ~ young + mid + old + edu + gdp + jobs + migration + population)) %>% 
  report()
```

Comment: The warning message provides the answer to your question.